# Designing the first stage (common emitter) of an amplifier that will drive an 8 ohm speaker

Tags: amplifier, bjt, ltspice, common-emitter, circuits

I have to design an amplifier (can be one stage or multiple thought I am thinking multiple) that will drive an 8-ohm speaker and have a gain of at least 10 V/V (about 20 dB) given Vcc = 9 V. It also needs to produce 6 V peak to peak without major distortion. After much hand calculation and several iterations, I cannot get the gain to be greater than 1. (Not ideal for a common emitter amp) I have included my circuit below. This is my first amplifier design so any help even not pertaining to the direct question would be great. (Things like how to calculate R1 and R2, etc.)

[image: my circuit]

[image: here is the output, I am getting an extremely low gain]

Comment: Note the ratio between your amplifier output impedance (a bit less than 4.5 K) and your speaker impedance.   Your input impedance looks pretty low also.

Comment: Consider how much current must flow in the speaker: 6v p-p into 8 ohms requires 0.75 amps p-p. You're going to need beefier transistor(s) than 2N3904.

Comment: @glen_geek do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @JohnD what is the best way to fix these issues?

Comment: Like you already said, you will need a multi-stage amplifier for this. Usually you'll first have a difference amplifier that implements global feedback, then a voltage amplifier (miller integrator), and finally a high-current output stage (class-AB). Here's a good example of such a DIY amp: https://www.diyaudio.com/community/threads/diyab-amp-the-honey-badger.192431/

Comment: You must never have an ac coupled load R smaller than Rc. YOu may be naive to think hFE will achieve simultaneous linear operation, with voltage and current gain without negative feedback.

Comment: @Nicola'sTesla Simple to understand and design would be a class-A output stage (two BJTs) and two other BJTs, total of four, and global NFB. Bootstrapping the 8 Ohm speaker allows a simple class-A base drive current source, too. However, given what I see above where you imagine that a 4.5 k Ohm output impedance can drive an 8 Ohm speaker or that we could suggest tweaks to R1 and R2 to fix your circuit, then perhaps it's not so simple to understand. You should start over but I don't believe you are ready to design anything on your own. (Oh, and are you expected to use an 9 V alkaline battery?)

Comment: @Nicola'sTesla [Here's a class-A design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SFNS.png) that will work as a proof of concept. It should achieve a gain greater than 10 (more than 20 dB, as you write and as shown in the plots.) It will dissipate power so I'm suggesting the D44H11's, which can handle it. Input impedance should be no worse than 10k Ohm, or so, but perhaps twice that. How you will explain this to anyone else is another matter. But there it is.

Comment: The title should read "the last stage" not the 1st